# Phase diagram in R

Tags: r

This is a borderline question for Stackoverflow, I know, but I am looking for a package. If I can't get an answer here I will transfer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/. I am looking for a R package or a method to create a phase diagram. This means I have e.g. two variables, like air pressure and temperature, and a binary variable (to make it easier) indicating if the substance is liquid or frozen. Below you find a typical example of a phase diagram. I need to estimate the transition borders or something however just in a case with two groups. Every hint is appreciated.

[image: Example]

Comment: Borderline or not, it is always good to [be specific when you ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), be it here or on CV. Exactly how should your diagram look like? Which data do you have? Which data do you need? You need to estimate "something"?

Comment: i added a picture to illustrate what i mean

Comment: You could use a combination of `geom_polygon` and `annotate` in `ggplot2` to create this sort of figure.

Comment: You should explain what information you have: if you have the phase for many points, it looks like a [nearest neighbour](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21572/how-to-plot-decision-boundary-of-a-k-nearest-neighbor-classifier-from-elements-o) problem; if you have an analytic description of the boundary, you can simply draw a few `polygon`s.

Comment: What about the critical point? How do you plan to merge the liquid/gas regions north and east of the critical point?

Comment: Interesting topic. But not a programming question as currently presented.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd I have empirical data. As I mention in my question in my case there are only two states: Equilibrium and No-Equilibrium. These two states are described by two Variables: Temperature and Pressure. I want to estimate the state boundaries in connection to the two "explanatory" variables.

Comment: @bdemarest I don't ask for a method but rather for a R package or a way to do it with ggplot or something.

Comment: linear or quadratic discriminant analysis?

Comment: Pretty easy to code if you give some guidance :)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! This brought me on the right track! It is about finding the decision boundaries of some classification algorithms like discriminant analysis or k-nearest-neighbours. see here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21572/how-to-plot-decision-boundary-of-a-k-nearest-neighbor-classifier-from-elements-o I believe this is the way to go. Should I answer this question myself?

Comment: you could.  You'll need to edit your question enough to get it reopened first, though.

Comment: ok! i mean you gave me the hint you can also answer the question and i will check it as correct, as you prefer it. otherwise i will do that tomorrow. it is absurdly late here in europe.

Answer (score 2):

I think about the closet you will get is function `diagram` in package `CHNOSZ`.  There's a lot to read about in this package and it has some nice vignettes.  But, it seems to calculate phase diagrams from first principles or theory. Perhaps if you look at the code for `diagram` you can figure out a fairly easy way to use your empirical data.